# Check if the timer is already started

Tags: winapi, mfc

How do I know if the timer is running or already started? Without waiting the time is elapsed?

```
UINT_PTR nID = SetTimer(123, 60x1000, NULL);  // Info after 1 Min.
bool bTimerStarted = false;     // do I need this bool var to check the state of the timer? 
if (nID == 123)
   bTimerStarted = true;
```

Comment: I don't think there is a winapi for that. Better keep a boolean to keep track whether you started the timer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. There is no API to query whether any given timer exists, without also resetting that timer (which [`SetTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) can do).

Then again, I cannot think of a situation where this would be required. Unless you've designed yourself into a corner previously. In that case, solve the architectural issue, and you'll find that you won't need this information either.

Comment: The situation is this: I don't want to reset the timer when it's already running. Yes, we can control it well with a boolean variable. I thought there might be a function like `TimerEnabled` or something I missed.

Comment: @TomTom If it is running it will trigger ....!

Comment: @TomTom `SetTimer()` returns an ID for the timer. It is your responsibility to keep track of that ID until either you call `KillTimer()` or the associated `HWND` (if any) is destroyed.  At which time, you can discard the ID.  So, if you have the ID onhand, then the timer is running. Period. Done.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code has to manage resetting the ID value whenever you call `KillTimer`.  So then `VERIFY(KillTimer(ID)); ID = 0;`

Comment: @franji1 yes, that would fall under "*At which time, you can discard the ID*" in my previous comment

Comment: @TomTom That's just re-stating the requirement, while avoiding to explain what the actual reason for that requirement is. I have yet to hear someone come up with a case where this requirement were justifiable. In the past, this requirement has always come up where a developer had taken the wrong turn earlier.